# C struct to void* pointer

Tags: c, void-pointers, structure

I have a struct defined as:

```
typedef struct {
   int type;
   void* info;
} Data;
```

and then i have several other structs that i want to assign to the void* using the following function:

```
Data* insert_data(int t, void* s)
{
    Data * d = (Data*)malloc(sizeof(Data));
    d->type = t;
    d->info = s;

    return d;
}

struct {
   ...
} Struct#;
```

then i just call

```
insert_data(1, variable_of_type_Struct#);
```

When i compile this it gives a warning

```
warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
```

i tried to cast the variable in the insert to (void*) but didn't work

```
insert_data(1, (void *) variable_of_type_Struct#);
```

How can i get rid of this warning?

Thanks

Comment: Casting the result of `malloc` [is unnecessary](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/512904). `Data * d = malloc(sizeof(Data));` would suffice.

Comment: I have feeling these sharp '#' characters are in your code as well. They are connected with macros, not sure what are they doing in your code.

Comment: Why was this struct {...} Struct#; in your code? I'm just curious.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Pass in the address of the struct, not a copy of it (i.e. not passed by value):

```
insert_data(1, &variable_of_type_Struct);
```

Comment: tried that. insert_data(1, (void *) &variable_of_type_Struct#); didn't work either

Comment: what type is your variable? btw no need to cast here.
Provede relevant types, we are no magicians to see whats hidden behind your typedefs.
Answer is valid though.

Comment: @Nitrate where you screwed up?

Comment: @hmjd don't trust Ideone. I have a very similar problem on gcc but my code actually compiles without warnings on Ideone.

Answer (score 5):

Pass a pointer to the struct object:

```
struct your_struct_type bla;

insert_data(1, &bla);
```

Answer (score 4):

Hope this program helps!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
   int type;
   void* info;
} Data;

typedef struct {
    int i;
    char a;
    float f;
    double d;  
}info;

Data* insert_data(int t, void* s)
{
    Data * d = (Data*)malloc(sizeof(Data));
    d->type = t;
    d->info = s;

    return d;
}

int main()
{
    info in; 
    Data * d;
    d = insert_data(10, &in);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: that is what i have. struct {
   ...
} Struct#;

then i just call

insert_data(1, variable_of_type_Struct#); which is a Struct# *variable

Comment: Say you are having `struct { ... }`, then you have to call `insert_data(int, struct *)` and not `insert_data(int, struct)`. Pass the address of the structure.

Comment: this is nice but you work with uninitialised data here. also ignoring any kind of checks (malloc, frees).

Comment: @AoeAoe Agree. I was trying to demonstrate how to send a address of a struct instead of struct.

Comment: @SangeethSaravanaraj you sent a copy of a pointer to struct imo.
to send adress of struct, he'd need _&struct_ .

Comment: @SangeethSaravanaraj how to chk that the d have info struct in the program ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure what this was:

```
struct {
   ...
} Struct#;
```

So, I cleaned up your program a little bit and got no warnings, after putting the address of the struct into the call,  `insert_data(1, &variable_of_type_Struct);`

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int type;
    void* info;
} Data;

Data* insert_data(int t, void* s);

Data variable_of_type_Struct;

Data* insert_data(int t, void* s)
{
    Data * d = (Data*)malloc(sizeof(Data));
    d->type = t;
    d->info = s;

    return d;
}

void test()
{
    insert_data(1, &variable_of_type_Struct);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`insert_data` waits for a `void*`, you put a `Data`.

```
insert_data(1, &variable_of_type_Struct#);
```

It miss a level of indirection.